scrollTop value after assigning an integer becomes floating in mobile browser and integer in desktop
let currentScrollTop = Math.round(scrollableDiv.scrollTop);
let lineHeightInt = Math.round(lineHeight);
console.log(currentScrollTop+lineHeightInt)
scrollableDiv.scrollTop = Math.round(currentScrollTop + lineHeightInt);
console.log(scrollableDiv.scrollTop, lineHeightInt);

logging the currentScrollTop+lineHeightInt gives 56 but logging the scrollableDiv.scrollTop after assigning currentScrollTop+lineHeightInt gives 55.76309585571 in mobile browser.
I want it to be same as desktop as 56.
